# How to call function in Cordova Plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, callback, cordova-plugins

I wrote a simple cordova plugin which displays an alert.
JS file: alert.js

```
module.exports = {
alert: function(title, message, buttonLabel, successCallback) {
cordova.exec(successCallback,
             null, // No failure callback
             "Alert",
             "alert",
             [title, message, buttonLabel]);
    }
};
```

Java File: Alert.java

```
package com.acme.plugin.alert;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Alert extends CordovaPlugin {
  protected void pluginInitialize() {
  }

  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) 
      throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("alert")) {
      alert(args.getString(0), args.getString(1), args.getString(2), callbackContext);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  private synchronized void alert(final String title, 
                                  final String message, 
                                  final String buttonLabel, 
                                  final CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(cordova.getActivity())
    .setTitle(title)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setNeutralButton(buttonLabel, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
        dialogInterface.dismiss();
        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, 0));
      }
    })
    .create()
    .show();
  }
}
```

How do I call the alert function of alert.js from another js? And what parameter should i pass to map to successCallback??

Comment: Check out this link - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/#the-javascript-interface your alert.js file already invokes the plugin code so i  not sure why u need an other js file to invoke alert.js

Comment: Sharing your `plugin.xml` would help.

Answer (score 2):

according to cordova git for creating plugin [see github page](https://github.com/RootSoft/Create-a-custom-Cordova-plugin) you can do it like this

Add the following code to wherever you need to call the plugin functionality:

```
 ‍‍‍cordova.plugins.<PluginName>.<method>();
```

where `<PluginName>` is your plugin name and `<method>` is your method.